# Alternate Android package naming convention

Tags: android

Every tutorial that I've read so far says that package name should be in reverse order of you domain. But what if I do not have a domain and want to publish an app in the market. What alternate package naming convention can I use?

Comment: Since you need a Web site to market your app, buy a domain name and use that for your package name.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Whatever you want; it's arbitrary.

Package naming is all about preventing conflicts, and creating logical groups of functionality. Not distributing your library? Just name it something reasonable.

"Not having a domain" isn't really the point--the reason that's a recommended practice is because they're unique to an organization, therefore unique across libraries, and unlikely to create conflicts.

Comment: Going off of Dave's answer you can always just default back to the common internal TLD `local`... so `local.nikhilrathod.someproject` would suffice.

Comment: @cfeduke Or pick a sultry tropic island and use that.